# How can i replace/convert number to string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which is working fine and returns `-1`:

```
SELECT -1 FROM (select SUM(column1), column2 
from documents where column2 is NULL group by column2) aa
where aa.column2_rid = rid and typ_doc in (4,2) and rownum = 1
```

But I want to convert/replace `-1` to string -> `'no_doc'`

If I use replace, it returns `0`

I think, because it's a number.....

`NVL` isn't working. `To_char(-1)` isn't working, too. Or I failed.

```
SELECT REPLACE('-1', '-1', 'no_doc') FROM ....
output: 0
SELECT REPLACE(-1, -1, 2) FROM .... 
output: 2
```

How can I achieve the expected output ? (`'no_doc'`)

Comment: can you undelete the question you just deleted re. the displaying of numbers please? I have an answer for you.

Comment: @Boneist i did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work:

```
select decode((select -1 from dual),-1,'no_doc','anything') from dual;
```

for your query:

```
 select decode((SELECT -1 FROM (select SUM(column1), column2 
 from documents where column2 is NULL group by column2) aa
 where aa.column2_rid = rid and typ_doc in (4,2) and rownum = 
 1),-1,'no_doc','anything') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just use `'no_doc'` instead of `-1` in the query?

```
select 'no_doc'
from (select SUM(column1), column2 
      from documents
      where column2 is NULL
      group by column2
     ) aa
where aa.column2_rid = rid and typ_doc in (4,2) and
      rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention, that i'm using NVL function to test my querries. NVL(query1,query2) - in first query i have numbers, so i can't use in 2. one `no_doc`. And yes, i know in that case, it's not the correct answer, but it help'd me a lot. I give u +1, 'cuz your answer is correct, too.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use NVL2 Function  also

```
SELECT NVL2(TO_CHAR(-1),'no_doc','Anyhing') FROM (
select SUM(column1), column2 from documents where column2 is NULL group by column2) aa
where aa.column2_rid = rid and typ_doc in (4,2) and rownum = 1
```